# ¿Cómo componer una fecha a partir de dos fechas distintas?

Tags: php, datetime

pongo este seudosecodigo que se que no funciona para explicar lo que quiero hacer:

```
resultado = 0 
fecha1 = 2000,1,1 2:21 
fecha2 = 2001,1,1 4:44 
resultado = fecha1-getAño(); 
resultado = fecha2-gerHora() 
dump(resultado) // 2011,1,1 T4:44
```

Por lo que estoy viendo tengo que descomponer las fechas en ano, mes, días , hora , minuto segundo, y luego recomponerla en una sola...

¿No hay otra manera más directa??
¡¡Tiene que haber una manera mas facil!!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida que esperas?, no me queda del todo clara la pregunta

Comment: +1 no entiendo del todo la pregunta, osea cual es el resultado que esperas

Comment: No veo como editar mi propia preguta...
bueno:
quiero un dataTime con la fecha de uno y la hora del otro:
resultado = 0
fecha1 = 2000,1,1 2:21
fecha2 = 2001,1,1 4:44
resultado = fecha1-getAño();
resultado = fecha2-gerHora()
dump(resultado) // 2011,1,1 T4:44

Comment: Existe el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/272872/edit) justo debajo de tu pregunta. Puedes añadir tu comentario en el texto para hacerlo más claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uno de los constructores de la clase `DateTime` necesita recibir un `string` del tipo "aaaa-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". Jugando con la función `format` de los objetos de la clase `DateTime` puedes construir un tercer `DateTime` con la unión de la fecha y la hora.

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2017-03-14');
$hora = new DateTime('13:37:42');

$fecha_hora = new DateTime($fecha->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hora->format('H:i:s'));

echo $fecha_hora->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**

Podrías hacer también la inversa. Partiendo de una fecha inicial desglosarla para sacar por un lado la fecha y por otro la hora. Como puedes ver la función `format` es muy útil.

```
$fecha_hora = new DateTime('2017-03-14 13:37:42');

$hora = new DateTime($fecha_hora->format('H:i:s'));
$fecha = new DateTime($fecha_hora->format('Y-m-d'));

echo 'Fecha: ' . $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Hora: ' . $hora->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Editada para añadir la operación inversa al ejemplo inicial. Partiendo de una fecha desglosarla en fecha por un lado y hora por el otro.

Comment: Esta perfe, justo estaba yo redactandole este mismo ejemplo

Comment: ¿y si $fecha_ahora ya existiese?
El procedimiento seria igual ¿no? machacarla con un new DataTime(fecha+' '+hora).
¿Correcto?

Comment: Eso depende de si necesitas usar posteriormente el valor anterior de `$fecha_hora` o no.